# parse nodes using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to read this xml file using Id on `<page>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <pages>
      <page id="NewsWatchVideo">
        <HeaderText>Newswatch</HeaderText>
        <BellowText>'abc'.In this video you will see how the press responded to the   .</BellowText>
        <FilePath>FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf</FilePath>
        <NextURL>/Home/OutStory</NextURL>
      </page>
      <page id="OutStory">
        <HeaderText>OUR STORY</HeaderText>
        <BellowText>Join the founders of United First Financial as they talk about how the business and concept was formed.</BellowText>
        <FilePath>FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf</FilePath>
        <NextURL>/Home/MMaoverViewVideo</NextURL>
      </page>
    </pages>
```

How can i get all the data by id?
I want to use  LINQ to XML to do this task.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "parse data by id"? Do you want to get a list of id's? Do you want to get all the data for one Id? Do you want to traverse id's in order?

Comment: i assumed 'get all the data for one id', but yeah, that's a very valid question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that your XML is loaded into `XmlDocument` variable '`doc`':

```
XmlNode page = doc.SelectSingleNode("//page[@id='OutStory']");
```

i.e. if you want to use a variable id:

```
XmlNode page = doc.SelectSingleNode("//page[@id='" + pageId + "']");
```

Both of which will allow you to do:

```
string headerText = page.SelectSingleNode("./HeaderText").InnerText;
```

**EDIT**

If you're working with LINQ to XML, your variable `doc` will be of the datatype `XDocument` and you'll write:

```
XElement page = doc.Descendants("page").Where(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == "OutStory").FirstOrDefault();
string headerText = page.Descendants("HeaderText").First().Value;
```

Comment: Dear @@David how can i do this task using LINQ to XML